# How to add a logo to an Overleaf template for a newspaper article?

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
\SetPaperName{The Report}
```

How do I add a logo after the title "The Report"? I want the logo to be next to the title, not below it.

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package.

Comment: That is probably an overleaf template so you could include link to exactly the one you use Link the public example file where we do not login not your private copy you need to include to the part above the other parts up to when papername is used plus any other bits between begin{document} to make it show the title and \end{document}

Comment: Looks like that space is occupied by \def\@paperlocation{Washington DC} in real papers it could be a logo or advert but in this template paskage it is intended to hold as space reserved for the area of publication

Comment: right i know, i just would rather put a logo. here is the link: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/newspaper-slash-news-letter-template/wjxxhkxdjxhw

Comment: Too much grief with fonts and missing secondary .sty need to take that to LianTze at Overleaf or see if tagging Question as an `overleaf` created problem gets her attention

Comment: ...which was originally from the `newspaper` package https://ctan.org/pkg/newspaper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your log in `\SetPaperLocation{...}` with an `\includegraphics` within a `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{...}` to have it vertically centered.

The template is from Overleaf, the link in your comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/newspaper-slash-news-letter-template/wjxxhkxdjxhw.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)

\SetPaperName{The Report}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{Committee Times}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}
\SetPaperSlogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\SetPaperPrice{Zero Dollars}


% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}


%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\byline{Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}

The package is basically a redefinition of the \verb+\maketitle+ command.  The model was the New York Times---hopefully I haven't violated any copyright laws.  I also had to redefine the plain pagestyle.  It kept me busy for a few nights after work.  The rest is packages other people have written.      

\begin{window}[2,r,\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{atom.jpg},\centerline{The Atom}] The \verb+multicol+ package allows using multiple columns without starting a new page.  Using floats is not possible in a columns environment, however with the \verb+picinpar+ package, I can set a picture inside a block of text---just like you one you see here.  Isn't \LaTeX{} cool?
And now we're just filling more space, and yet more space.  
\end{window}
\closearticle


\headline{Another Headline}
This is just an example to fill up some space, but as long as I have your attention, I'll give some newspaper advice.

I suppose we could also show how an equation is type set:
\begin{displaymath}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{displaymath}
and there you have it.  

\lipsum[1-4]

\closearticle

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any change I could ask a follow up? I know how to add figures to be in a single column. Is there a way to have a figure stretch across both columns? I have 

\begin{window}[2,r,\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{ex.png},\centerline{Ex.}]  
\end{window}

When I change the width to 7 in, it does not go across the page like I would want. any suggestions?

Comment: @JacksonHart Do you mean an image in the title or in the text? Could you please ask another question (with this one linked, as it's its follow-up) with an image of what you like to achieve (a photo of an hand-drawing is enough)? Thanks!